# Explicitly Declaring List of Int?

Tags: ocaml, reason

How can I explicitly mark the type of `let myList = [1, 2, 3];` as a `list of int's`?

I tried `let xs: 'int list = [1,2,3];` unsuccessfully through [Try ReasonML](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?reason=DYUwLgBAHgzhC8EDaBGANAJjQZgLoG4AoQ0SAQwBMKUEIAKKASgQD5oIBqCFIk8CMrWwQAPm0rVR4qjTECZvUhABGtMov6wAXBADkASwB2kYPpiREqTDgJA).

Comment: Note that the `'` prefix in front of a type marks it as a type variable. So it would be interpreted as something like `def xs[Int]: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 6):

It's `let xs: list(int) = [1,2,3];` in Reason or `let xs: int list = [1; 2; 3]` in OCaml.